# Why kafka write null data to the database?

Tags: mysql, node.js, apache-kafka, nestjs

I am working on a nestjs project. My project gets data from Kafka's topic and writes the data to the database (mysql). If I read hundreds of messages from Kafka, most of them can be written to the database correctly. However, some messages can be written to the database with a null value(the database can have that record but with a null value in all columns). Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're missing a filter for null-valued Kafka records.

Ideally, you shouldn't be writing to the database using NestJS, if you are able to run a standalone Kafka Connect process.

Comment: Hi, I am pretty sure that the data from Kafka is not null. For example, on the first try, I read "a" from Kafka, but it would write null to the database (using Prisma). The same data input can be written to the database correctly on the second try.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "second try". Are you not committing the offsets? Ultimately, we'd need to see your code why null might end up in the database. I have no experience with Prisma